# What to do when paginator is not allowed on a collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two entities: `Post` (posts) and `Tag` (tags). They both are in many-to-many relationship. So I have a pivot table called `PostTag` (post_tag). I want to list all the tags *[including **a) pivot table** and **b) post title**]* which belong to those posts whose author is the logged in user. So I did something like this:

```
$tags = collect();
$posts = Post::where('user_id', auth()->id())->with('tags')->get();
$posts->each(function($post, $key) use ($tags){
    $post->tags->each(function($tag, $key) use ($tags, $post) {
        $tag->post_title = $post->title;
        $tags->push($tag);
    });
});
return $tags;
```

However, I also need to paginate the result. So I attempted to return this instead:

```
return $tags->paginate(10);
```

But paginate is not a method of `Collection` (Maybe of `Builder`)

The relationship methods are:

```
// Post.php
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withPivot('updated_at');
}
// Tag.php
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

I have a feeling that there must be some easier way of doing it which I may not know:

```
PostTag::someQueryThatFetchesThoseTagsWithPostTitle();
// If I could do something like this, paginate() would have been available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tags::query()->where('posts.user_id', auth()->id())
             ->join('post_tag', 'post_tag.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
             ->join('posts', 'post_tag.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
             ->selectRaw('tags.*, posts.title as post_title')
             ->paginate(10);
```

You can just optimize your query in order to return what you want selecting what you need.

This should be even faster.

Comment: Unknown column `tags.post_title` is not found field list. I explicitly appended the post_title to the tags collection `$tag->post_title = $post->title;`. There is no `post_title` column in the schema of `tags` table. You may have missed that...

Comment: sorry, i correct immediately, i misunderstood your request

Comment: one minor problem though. It's not fetching the pivot table: `return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withPivot('updated_at');`

Comment: just add it to the select ->selectRaw('tags.*, posts.title as post_title, post_tag.updated_at as post_tag_updated_at') just pay attention to the field name if any other table has the same column

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own pagination with `LengthAwarePaginator` with this piece of code I'm using in my projects sometimes.

```
//Get current page form url e.g. &page=6
$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
//Number of results in pagination
$paginate = 10;

//Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
$currentPageSearchResults = $tags->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $paginate, $paginate)->all();

//Create our paginator and pass it to the view
$paginatedSearchResults = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, $tags->count(), $paginate);
```

Where `$paginatedSearchResults` returns pagination object.

Comment: There seems to be some issues with the page traversal. Only change I made to your code was that I'm taking the row per page value from the request: `$paginate = request('rowsPerPage') ?? 5;` If not provided, defaulting to 5. I have 7 rows, I expect to see 5 rows in the first page and 2 rows in the second. However it shows the first page with 5 rows, but when I click next, it shows nothing. And I checked from the network tab that it did retrieve the two rows. Don't know why couldn't display it. Working on it. For now I am upvoting the answer to appreciate your help.

Comment: In your view, did you use `$paginatedSearchResults->links()` to generate links for pages? And also check your url for parameters, it should have something like `?page=2` in order to view your last 2 rows.

Comment: In your view, did you use $paginatedSearchResults->links() to generate links for pages? // No. It's a single page application

Comment: Ok, but still, when making an ajax request, or whatever, you should have page parameter in your url. 
Anyway, my answer is used when you cannot create a paginator from query builder. So @leonardo gasparini 's answer is the right one to use, as you already checked it as the right one. :D